# What is the shortest hash with Nodejs crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

What is the shortest string hash algo in the nodejs crypto module? Is there anything similar to crc32, which produces  8-character string , but unfortunately is not natively supported by crypto (I know that there are external modules, but I'm limited to built-in crypto). Hash collision probabilities is not important for my application (cache bursting).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a XOF hash function like `shake256` which supports the `outputLength` option (in bytes):

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

function createHash(data, len) {
    return crypto.createHash("shake256", { outputLength: len })
      .update(data)
      .digest("hex");
}

console.log(createHash("foo", 2))
// 1af9
console.log(createHash("foo", 8))
// 1af97f7818a28edf
```